# Como pasar un parámetro o ninguno desde la consola a un constructor?

Tags: c#, poo, sobrecarga

Como puedo sobrecargar un constructor para que se cree una instancia dependiendo los datos entregados por consola?

Detalle:

tengo una clase AUTO con 2 constructores:

```
1.- Constructor por defecto:
public Auto(){
    Console.WriteLine("Constructor sin parametros");
}

2.- Constructor con 1 parametro:
public Auto(String marca){
    this.Marca = marca
}
```

En el main necesito pedir al usuario que ingrese una marca, si lo hace se instancia el constructor 2, si no, se instancia el 1.

El problema que tengo es instanciar el constructor correcto según la acción del usuario, si lo hago encadenando el constructor funciona bien(this:), pero funciona si escribo o borro el parámetro de entrada yo y ejecuto el programa desde la consola, la idea es dejar el programa de forma funcional.

después de crear la instancia este objeto se usa para llamar varios metodos que tendría que duplicar si creo un objeto para cada constructor, y si después necesito crear N constructores más sería una locura.

Gracias de antemano.

Saludos.

Comment: Pero esto se resuelve con un `if` o existe algo que no estoy entendiendo ???

Answer (score 2):

La mejor forma es que una vez leida la respuesta del usuario preguntes si la misma es nula o vacia, si lo es llamas al constructor sin parametros, en caso contrario llamas al otro constructor.
Por ejemplo:

```
Auto auto;
string marca = Console.ReadLine();
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(marca.Trim()))
{
   auto = new Auto();
}
else
{
   auto = new Auto(marca);
}
```